# Serialize to XML without formatting (tabs) using JMS Serializer

Tags: php, xml, serialization, jms-serializer

I am using [xsd2php](https://github.com/goetas-webservices/xsd2php) library (which itself uses [jsm-serializer](https://github.com/schmittjoh/serializer)). When I serialize object, it returnes formatted XML, for example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<priceRequest>
  <appId>PC</appId>
  <appVersion>3.0</appVersion>
</priceRequest>
```

How can I tune serializer to output XML without formatting, like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><priceRequest><appId>PC</appId><appVersion>3.0</appVersion></priceRequest>
```

Right now I build serializer like the following:

```
$serializerBuilder = SerializerBuilder::create();

$serializerBuilder->configureHandlers(function (HandlerRegistryInterface $handler) use ($serializerBuilder) {
    $serializerBuilder->addDefaultHandlers();
    $handler->registerSubscribingHandler(new BaseTypesHandler());
    $handler->registerSubscribingHandler(new XmlSchemaDateHandler());
    $handler->registerSubscribingHandler(new AnyTypeHandler());
});

$this->serializer = $serializerBuilder->build();
```

And then simply serialize the data:

```
$this->serializer->serialize($data, $format, $context);
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Look at here [JSM Serializer - YAML Reference](http://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer/master/reference/yml_reference). I think you can use the `inline` properties. On the other hand, if you have to create the [custom serialization handler](https://github.com/goetas-webservices/xsd2php#dealing-with-xsdanytype-or-xsdanysimpletype), maybe you can use some properties of the JMS Serializer, look here [Metadata/Driver/XmlDriver.php](https://github.com/schmittjoh/serializer/blob/master/src/JMS/Serializer/Metadata/Driver/XmlDriver.php)

Comment: @YulioAlemanJimenez, thank you for your comment. I guess `inline` property regards not the formatting, but structure: it puts the element to the root.

Answer (score 0):

After a while, I found the solution, not sure if it the right one, but it does the trick.

[`XmlSerializationVisitor`](https://github.com/schmittjoh/serializer/blob/master/src/JMS/Serializer/XmlSerializationVisitor.php) has public method `setFormatOutput`, and `$formatOutput` defaults to `true`.

[`SerializerBuilder`](https://github.com/schmittjoh/serializer/blob/master/src/JMS/Serializer/SerializerBuilder.php) sets visitors by default, so the `$formatOutput` of the default XML serializer visitor also defaults to `true`:

We can set our own serializer visitors using `setSerializationVisitor`. The interesting thing about this, that if we use this method, no other default visitors will be set (including deserialize visitor). So if you have to set one non-default, you have to set all.

Keeping in mind written above, we can configure our serializer for XML serialization and deserialization like the following:

```
use JMS\Serializer\SerializerBuilder;
use JMS\Serializer\Naming\CamelCaseNamingStrategy;
use JMS\Serializer\Naming\SerializedNameAnnotationStrategy;
use JMS\Serializer\Accessor\DefaultAccessorStrategy;
use JMS\Serializer\XmlSerializationVisitor;
use JMS\Serializer\XmlDeserializationVisitor;

$serializerBuilder = SerializerBuilder::create();

$propertyNamingStrategy = new SerializedNameAnnotationStrategy(new CamelCaseNamingStrategy());
$accessorStrategy = new DefaultAccessorStrategy();
$serializationVisitor = new XmlSerializationVisitor($propertyNamingStrategy, $accessorStrategy);
$serializationVisitor->setFormatOutput(false); // <= So this is what all the fuss is about.
$deserializationVisitor = new XmlDeserializationVisitor($propertyNamingStrategy);

$serializerBuilder->setSerializationVisitor('xml', $serializationVisitor);
$serializerBuilder->setDeserializationVisitor('xml', $deserializationVisitor);

$this->serializer = $serializerBuilder->build();
```